# How to convert a number of milliseconds to a human-readable time interval?

Tags: freemarker

In my FTL file, I use a variable like this:

```
${millisecondsSpent}
```

It represents an integer duration of a task in milliseconds. Ideally, I'd like to convert that to a human-readable string, such as "1 hour, 5 minutes, 7 seconds". I checked [built-ins for date/time](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html) and didn't find anything.

I suppose I could write my own converter, but I thought I'd ask if there's a better way first.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.3.31 there's nothing built in for that, so you have to write your own converter.